# Puppet agent error

Tags: puppet

I am getting this error message when i am tryin to ryn `puppet agent --test` on my graylog server(centos 7), I am pretty sure it is super simple to fix but I do't know how?

```
Warning: The package type's allow_virtual parameter will be changing its default value from false to true in a future release. If you do not want to allow virtual packages, please explicitly set allow_virtual to false.
```

(at /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/type.rb:816:in `set_default')

/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/type.rb line 816 is the paste below but I can't figure out where i should set the allow_virtual false ?

```
 809 def set_default(attr)
 810     return unless klass = self.class.attrclass(attr)
 811     return unless klass.method_defined?(:default)
 812     return if @parameters.include?(klass.name)
 813 
 814     return unless parameter = newattr(klass.name)
 815 
 816     if value = parameter.default and ! value.nil?
 817       parameter.value = value
 818     else
 819       @parameters.delete(parameter.name)
 820     end
 821   end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the default of that parameter to true.

Like this (in your main manifest):

```
Package {
   allow_virtual => true,
}
```

I think at this point you should be setting it to true, Puppet 4 is out for a while and it makes sense to already set it up so it will work then too.

See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.6/reference/release_notes.html#changes-to-rpm-behavior-with-virtual-packages for more details.

Comment: Sry for a noob question here but should i do it on the client or the master?

Comment: What do you mean? You should set this preferably in a manifest that all your nodes use.